# Im having PagerAdapter with 2 Fragments and i want editText data to auto update(Transfer Data)

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

Im having PagerAdapter with 2 Fragments, after/while I enter data in first fragment1 editText1 i want the same data to be shown(update) in the next swiped fragment2 editText2

here is my Git-Hub...some one please help me with this 
( https://github.com/raj5140/AAASwipe_Update )

I have tried tried many different ways, but it does not work, some1 please help me with this.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Amazing Bro....u fixed my issue...Tnx a Ton

Comment: i have one last doubt....lets say in same project if i have a button Submit in main activity....when i click on it...i want to get Edittext1.getText.toString(); there...im getting nullPointer Exception for editText.....im stuck there now....any idea?

Comment: You need to create a variable that will hold the reference to editText. For example ```EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText)``` then you can access the string that is inside the editText. ```String str = editText.getText.tostring();```

Comment: Jesus i made a silly mistake....by bad...issue resolved.. gr8 Tnx a lot bro

Comment: no problem! that's how you learn. happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so i just saw your code. I used robot's EventBus libaray for this purpose.

First i added 
`compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'` in build.gradle synced the project.

Then i made following changes in the fragments here is the code

**Welcome_Slide1.java**

```
public class Welcome_Slide1 extends Fragment {


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_slide1, container, false);
            EditText editText = (EditText) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(s.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
            return myFragmentView;
        }
}
```

**Welcome_Slide2**

```
public class Welcome_Slide2 extends Fragment {

EditText editText;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_slide2, container, false);
    editText = (EditText) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    return myFragmentView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(String s){
    editText.setText(s);
}
}
```

I hope this will help you. For more here is the [link](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to library documentation